# Django HttpResponseRedirect reverse function in tutorial

Tags: django, http, redirect

Can someone please explain what is going on here with the [Django Tutorial Part 4](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial04/)

Specifically, how the map function is working?

I understand that URLs shouldn't be hardcoded in the view functions.

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('mysite.polls.views.results', args=(p.id,)))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `reverse` function has access to the URL map that Django uses to find a view function for incoming URLs.  In this case, you pass in a view function, and the arguments it will get, and it finds the URL that would map to it.  Then the HttpResponseRedirect function creates a response that directs the browser to visit that URL.

This is a way of saying, "Now call the mysite.polls.views.results view."

Answer (score 1):

When defining URLs in Django you have the option of specifying a name to your URL: url(regex, view, kwargs=None, name=None, prefix='') such as what they do [in the tutorial](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial04/#use-generic-views-less-code-is-better) naming it `poll_results`:

```
url(r'^(?P<object_id>\d+)/results/$', 
'django.views.generic.list_detail.object_detail',
dict(info_dict, template_name='polls/results.html'), 'poll_results'),
```

This pattern has one named group: `object_id`. The reverse function looks up the URL pattern named `poll_results` and passes `p.id` to be used for `object_id` in the URL pattern.  The function returns the URL built from the regex and the passed parameters.